# MOK manager utility won't show up on reboot on Ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot)

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, uefi, grub-efi, secure-boot

As it is generally known, naively install and start virtualbox 5.2.4 on ubuntu 16.04 will meet secure boot issue:

```
$ virtualbox
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (4.10.0-42-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed
```

Thus, I am trying to make virtualbox work with secure boot enabled, basically I followed posts using mokutil: [https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/](http://I%20am%20trying%20to%20make%20virtualbox%20work%20with%20secure%20boot%20enabled,%20basically%20I%20followed%20posts%20using%20mokutil:https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/)

But on my ASUS QT425Q with secure boot enabled and fast boot disabled. After I import the public key set the passcode

```
# mokutil --import /root/module-signing/MOK.der
  input password:
  input password again:
```

The MOK manager utility won't show up on reboot. And I can enroll the key, could anyone help me figure out what is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last, I solved this problem by reordering the booting order with the help from the mokutil author **lcp**, following this post fix this issue:
https://github.com/lcp/mokutil/issues/11#issuecomment-356159399

**1. Check whether MOK files exist.**

```
   $ sudo -i
   # cd /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
   # ls Mok*
   MokAuth-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
   MokNew-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
   MokSB-605dab50-e046-4300-abb6-3dd810dd8b23
```

**2. Check the order of the boot.**

```
   # efibootmgr -v
   BootCurrent: 0000
   Timeout: 2 seconds
   BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002
   Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
   Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager   HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
   Boot0002* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
```

**3. Reorder the boots.**

So in the previous printout, for instance, we need to swap the **Boot0000*** with **Boot0002***.

```
# efibootmgr -o 0002,0001,0000
# efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,0000
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI)
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...d................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,dabc2835-8f96-4429-ba98-3abadcfcaa57,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
```

**4. Now reboot.** And the Mok manager should shows up on boot.

Hope this can help others.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to call up the Mok tool. Just sign the kernal module with sha256,

```
 /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 <key> <x509> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vboxdrv.ko
 /usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 <key> <x509> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vboxnetadp.ko
/usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 <key> <x509> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vboxnetflt.ko
/usr/src/linux-headers-`uname -r`/scripts/sign-file sha256 <key> <x509> /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vboxpci.ko
```

Then reinstall the modules to the kernel.