# Kubuntu 20.04 failed to upgrade to kernel 5.8 with CPU AMD Ryzen 5 4500U

Tags: drivers, kernel, gpu, amd-processor

I installed Kubuntu 20.04 to my new machine with CPU AMD Ryzen 5 4500U， unfortunately, the GPU failed to function properly to adjust the display lightness.

Friends guided me that the kernel 5.4 released earlier than AMD Ryzen 5， so updating kernel to latest 5.8 might be a decent solution.

I followed the instruction [How to Install Linux Kernel 5.8 in Ubuntu](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/install-linux-kernel-5-8-ubuntu/)

```
cd /tmp/
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.0-050800_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/amd64/linux-headers-5.8.0-050800-generic_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.8.0-050800-generic_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.8/amd64/linux-modules-5.8.0-050800-generic_5.8.0-050800.202008022230_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

However, after restart it report error:

```
error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-050800-generic has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first
Press any key to continue...
```

I re-installed the kernel 5.8 more than twice, it report such the identical error.

How could solve the problem?

Comment: File a bug report with super-specific detail about the hardware that is not recognized...since the kernel developer who reads it won't have access to your hardware.

Comment: The `5.8` kernel is not officially supported by Ubuntu. But your problem looks like a Secure Boot issue. Disable it. Instead of using an unsupported kernel, it is better to use drivers from AMD site and the `5.4` kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel is not signed. Turning off secure-boot in your bios could help.
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081472/vmlinuz-4-18-12-041812-generic-has-invalid-signature) could be the same issue.