# WI-FI option is not showing

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu

I brought a new Asus [laptop](https://www.flipkart.com/asus-tuf-gaming-f15-core-i5-10th-gen-8-gb-512-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650-144-hz-fx506lh-hn258t-laptop/p/itm834e03127f443) which has latest `WI-FI 6`. I installed `Kubuntu 21.04` alongside Windows 10 (dual boot). Furthermore, I can use both Ethernet and WI-FI in Windows, but I can only use Ethernet in Kubuntu. There is no wireless connection option is showing in networking options.
The same problem encountered when I was using `Deepin OS` in this laptop.

**Edit 1 :**

Output of  **`sudo lshw -c`** network

```
[sudo] password for abhishek: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c2100000-c21fffff memory:c2200000-c2203fff memory:c2204000-c2204fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 15
       serial: fc:34:97:95:8c:42
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.40 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c5204000-c5204fff memory:c5200000-c5203fff
```

Ouput of **`sudo lspci`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Thermal Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d3
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b5 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake LPC Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH SPI Controller
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5404 (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

**How to solve the problem ?**

#### EDIT 2 :

I follow command line [steps](https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/) and downloaded [Linux kernel 5.12.8](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.12.8/) (1,3,4,6 line *.deb) to install kernel 5.12.8 which support WI-FI 6.

I reboot my laptop and it first shows
[image]
to select kernel version. (As by default it selected that kernel which I just installed). I hit enter, and then it shows [image]

What should I do now ?

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of actionable information here. Can you [edit] your question to include the output of: (1) `sudo lshw -c network` (2) the output of `sudo lspci`. This will contain information about the hardware and drivers for your network device.

Comment: Edited. Please watch my edit section.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1344040/1222991) may be what you’re looking for 

Comment: Please see my `Edit 2` section. I follow some steps to upgrade my kernel to 5.12.8 but ....

Comment: You have three options: (1) disable "Secure Boot" in your UEFI/BIOS (2) [sign the custom kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182830/1222991) (3) install Ubuntu 21.04 overtop the existing installation

Comment: Thanks, done. Now my WI-FI is working, but sometimes it doesn't detect WI-FI. So I need to reboot again. If so again, then reboot again.

Comment: No worry. But please take a look on my [NEW question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363706/slow-shutdown-in-kubuntu).