# Slow shutdown in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown

I just installed `Kubuntu 21.04`. I am using dual boot (Windows10 + Kubuntu). Kubutnu takes  around `20 secs` to shut down. Boot time is 3-4 seconds fast because of SSD. Problem is only with Kubuntu while shutdown. It takes long time.
For the solution, I go to this [askUbtunu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369613/how-to-troubleshoot-slow-shutdown), but I don't have `sendsigs` file in `/etc/init.d/`.

**Why does it so ?**

Comment: Compare the timestamps from `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`, the end of the logs (`-e`) of the previous boot (`-b -1`)