# is it possible to upgrade to kernel 5.14?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, security, 21.04

is it possible to upgrade to kernel 5.14 ?
what happens if I did it while now am using 21.04 with kernel 5.11.0.34 and kernel 5.14 is not supported in public?

should I always install other security updates myself or it will automatically be notified by system?

am not technical guy, however, I would love to learn some things that might happen IF I took the rist and updated my kernel right now.

Comment: Is there any specific reason (e.g. hardware incompatibility) you want to upgrade? If not, don't upgrade. The default kernels in Ubuntu do get security patches.

Comment: just in love to be with latest updates specially the security ones. as kernel 5.14 has sec features like mem_secret for secure memory and CPU mitigates of spec and meltd.

Comment: *as kernel 5.14 has sec features like mem_secret for secure memory and CPU mitigates of spec and meltd* -- Do you really need them? Yes, it is possible to upgrade. You can download kernels from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, but it is strongly recommended that you do not change the default kernels unless you know what you are doing, and how to revert back.

Comment: any idea why ubuntu 21.10 might not use 5.14 kernel?

Comment: Because of this reason. https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: oh, I see. thank you sir for your quick reply :)

Comment: If you want the latest don't use Ubuntu and switch to another distribution. What you want is a rolling release or bleeding edge. Debian experimental provides 5.14 (hence the name).  Ubuntu  intentionally only uses "stable".

Comment: Bad idea IMO.  Generally with Linux software, the latest is *not* the greatest. Newer software has less testing and is more likely to contain bugs and other problems. We call it "bleeding edge" because you might get cut.  You are already running a standard release which is more experimental than an LTS release, by forfeiting the testing that the Ubuntu kernel gets with Ubuntu you are increasing the chances of bugs and crashes even more. If you do not have a very good need to have a newer kernel, and you do not want to be a guinea pig, leave it be.

Comment: @eeesa I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363659/wi-fi-option-is-not-showing) yesterday. So I need to upgrade my Kernel version to solve the problem. Before upgrading your kernel, see - [Upgrading to a mainline kernel is usually not a good idea](https://askubuntu.com/a/162617/820407). By the way, If you feel any problem after upgrading kernel then you can uninstall it or you can also choose for kernel version during boot time.

Comment: thank you ubuntu community. you really helped me a lot. highly appreciated your answers.

Comment: To answer Your question: The `5.13.14` (and up) and `5.14` are built against `glibc 2.34` which is not available for Ubuntu `21.04`.